# Not able to delete class in quickbook in php

Tags: php, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

The code goes like this:

```
$dataService = QuickbookConnection::createQBConnection();
$serviceType = IntuitServicesType::QBO;
$classObj = new IPPClass();
$classObj->Id = $classId;
try{ 
    $resultingObj = $dataService->Delete($classObj);
} catch (Exception $e){     
    $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: Try to print the error, and see what it's saying.

Comment: I am not getting any error. $resultingObj is blank object and class id entry not getting delete from quickbook.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with update class api. Its updates all the fields but not updating Active flag. Is any thing wrong with code?

```
$dataService = QuickbookConnection::createQBConnection();
$serviceType = IntuitServicesType::QBO;

$classObj = new IPPClass();

// Build a query
$oneQuery = new QueryMessage();

$oneQuery->sql         = "SELECT";
$oneQuery->entity      = "Class";
$oneQuery->whereClause = array("Id='".$QbLocationID."'", );

// Run a query
$queryString = $oneQuery->getString();
$entities    = $dataService->Query($queryString);

if ($entities)
{
    foreach( $entities as $class )
    {
        if ( $class->Id == $QbLocationID )
        {
            $classObj = $class;
        }
    }
}

$classObj->Name   = 'Mumbai';  // Name updating
$classObj->Active = false;

try{ 
    $resultingObj = $dataService->Add($classObj);

} catch (Exception $e){ 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In QBO, you can only make a class as inactive by update operation. You can't delete it.
Delete works only for transactions.